# @Html.DropDownListFor Size (or) style not working

Tags: model-view-controller, dropdownlistfor

```html
     @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.DSelected, Model.DList, new { @class = "mdb-select colorful-select dropdown-primary", @style ="height:35px;" ,  @size="2" })
```

Why doesn't height or size property work :(
I want to set the height so as to prevent the overflow of the items.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The `size` attribute is only used with `<select multiple>` (I.e. a List-box). It has no effect in single (drop-down list) mode.

Use CSS width/height to specify the layout size of the rendered `<select>`.